# How do you achieve that black/transparent look in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, black

How do you achieve this look:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I know we have duplicate questions here, but I couldn't find any. So here's a youtube link to a duotone tutorial: https://youtu.be/3SKii_OLrHs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the *Background* color and the *Main Image* layer. Click the *Main Image* layer thumbnail holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Win to load the transparency selection and copy it.

[image: Main Image]

Make a *Fill Color* layer

[image: Fill Color]

Click the *Fill Color* layer mask holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to see its content

[image: mask]

With the selection active, paste

[image: paste]

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> Win to invert. Click the *Color Fill* thumbnail and hid the *Main Image* layer.

[image: invert]

Click the mask and apply levels: reduce midtones increasing shadows and highlights

[image: levels]

**Work process**

[image: animated gif]

**Result**

[image: end]

<sub>Original image from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/RJ1ZvY2f-2U)</sub>

Comment: When i make a black Color Fill the selection disappears and when i paste the image into the selected mask it just makes another layer including the picture.

Comment: Still, this happens https://imgur.com/a/UuL71bK

Comment: Answer updated with animated work process